# Shouldn't this question be moved to the Wiki?

Tags: discussion

So someone is trying to delete answers to this closed question: [Resources to Create Applications with a Great User Interaction Experience? [closed]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/165985/resources-to-create-applications-with-a-great-user-interaction-experience)

Should this question be moved to the Wiki like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) one? Or moved to https://ux.stackexchange.com/ or something else?

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354767/is-the-format-of-the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list-question-sub-optimal

Comment: @YohDeadfall so the _C++ books_ question is the only question that is permitted to exist in this format? Or are there any other questions like this which are acceptable?

Comment: The C++ Books list is marked as having *significant historical value*, which later questions cannot achieve any more because questions such as that one are not permitted any more.

Comment: Don't know. But as Servy said, it's maintained, and while the community do that job it would be alive.

Comment: I thought there was a whole set of these old off-topic questions with book recommendations. Which are kept because they were useful despite being off-topic. But it seems only the C++ one is considered to be Ok. So why are the other ones are not deleted?

Comment: @Dmitry For the same reason basically all bad questions haven't been deleted.  There are way more bad questions out there than the people who take the time to use their moderation privileges are able to handle.

Comment: Comment: "Is there one in this list that stands out above the others?"  Yup, and that's how they go wrong every single time.  The C++ book list is just a get-off-my-lawn list, that's considered normal in that tag.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The question should just be deleted.  Its vote count and view count indicate it's not particularly useful, at least not enough so that it'd be worth keeping despite being *wildly* inappropriate for the site.  It also hasn't been updated by anyone in many years, so it's very clearly not being kept up to date.

If UX wants to create a question like this, that's up to that site to determine.  If they do, they can make their own.  Old questions cannot be migrated to other sites, so moving this one isn't an option, for good reason.

Comment: So the answer is _"something else"_ i.e. delete the whole question? Ok got it.