# List of recommended books in other languages?

Tags: discussion

Is a list like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) also made for other common programming languages? (on SO)

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/354767/is-the-format-of-the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list-question-sub-optimal

Comment: Where should I have asked a question like this, if not on meta SO?

Comment: Amazon. Sort by reviews.

Comment: @Will My question was not how to find good books. As there is a list for c++, I wanted to know if there are list of other common programming languages, too.

Comment: Amazon. Sort by reviews.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, it is not (there have been attempts and you might find some to still remain but  they are not encouraged or considered a good use of the Q/A model.)

When you would start such list today as a question it would be closed as an recommendation/shopping question.

[Tag wiki's](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/c%23/info) are a great place to curate lists of all kind of offsite resources, including books.