# Are questions asking for one exhaustive list on-topic?

Tags: discussion, vote-to-close, close-reasons, list-questions

I've come across [Which HTML attributes has different name on Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62374654/1048572) and its follow-up [What is the exhaustive list of HTML attributes that behave differently on Javascript DOM API?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62375187/1048572) and found them to not fit in the Q&A format. (They're currently both closed, no need to take action).

However, it seems the close-voters could not agree on the vote reason. What should be used? Or should the question be allowed after all?

I did vote as off-topic, "asking for references", myself, but it's not really that. The question is specific, not too-arbitrary and *could* be answered in a self-contained post. However, it still seems like a bad fit for the site to me: it's too hard to maintain an answer to stay up-to-date, and it doesn't make sense to receive multiple answers.

I thought we had a policy for such questions on meta, but couldn't find anything.

Comment: That the users don't agree on a close reason doesn't make a question on-topic.  You already know this.  More than once, I've seen people argue about a close reason over a question that is clearly unsuitable anyway.

Comment: In any case, corporate decided to simplify the close reasons, and in doing so stripped some of the meaning from them.  The close reason you're reaching for is "Too Broad", which used to contain as its wording (more or less), "There are too many possible answers."

Comment: Sure miss the old "too broad" reason. It's explanation was more robust than current reasoning. In fact most of the new explanations seem overly vague

Comment: @RobertHarvey I'm not implying that it's on-topic, I just was uncertain which close reason to use myself. "Too broad" might be fine, however I'm not sure if "too many possible answers" fits for exhaustible lists. (There might be only a few attributes after all).

Comment: BTW, I find it hilarious that the solution to close a unsuitable question is going by duplicate, which only assures that neither question is deleted by roomba.

Comment: @Braiam I sometimes (ab)use my mjölnir powers when finding an unsuitable question that I want to close single-handledly and think that other questions will be useful for the asker.

Comment: [Why do 'some examples' and 'list of things' questions get closed?](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7537/31260)

Comment: Yeah, it may be useful for the asker, but so would be a simple comment. That's why I advocate for other close reasons to require less votes or to be allowed to single handedly be closed by user with the tag badges. It would make the system work as intended, by not encouraging that behavior.

Answer (score 7):

After some digging around, I found some old discussions on MSE. Most of them were discussing subjective "list questions" (questions with multiple possible answers, which are still off-topic), but also [Is there a canonical response to back up the statement that "list questions are bad"?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148097/183280) and [Are there "good" list questions as opposed to "bad" list questions?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/180335/183280). From the [Rachel](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/302677/rachel)'s answer there:

> I find list questions to be accepted on most SE sites if:
>
> - There is a limited number of items in that list
> - The parameters are clearly defined
> - The list is unlikely to change over time
> - An answer is posted that contains every one of these items
>
> The last part is really the key to a list question's success on SE.
> Unfortunately as the  question asker, this isn't something you can
> usually provide.

Answer (score 6):

Many times questions fit more than one reason to be closed, this is one of those many cases. Instead of trying to figure out the single guidance that this question run afoul, maybe target all of them:

- a list of X;
- not definitive;
- doesn't foment answers that explain neither the how or why;
- open ended;
- asking us to regurgitate the documentation verbatim;
- trivia; and from this we can infer that
- it's not a problem that you find on software development

Many close reasons fit any of those criteria, in many contexts. Don't get too worked up trying to come with The One™ close reason, as long as there's any reason to close it, vote to close. If you are that bothered, you also have the option to write your own close reason.

Comment: Do we have a meta entry that rules "a list of X" is off-topic? I would've linked it in a custom close reason if I could have found it.

Comment: I'm sure that "a list of X" used to be in the non-meta help section, but it seems to have disappeared over the years.

Comment: @Bergi there are some references in this blog post https://stackoverflow.blog/2010/09/29/good-subjective-bad-subjective/ "“How?” and “Why?” has more lasting value than a bunch of product-feature bullet points or a giant enumerated list, no matter how extensive."

Comment: Seems like a question asking for a list would run afoul of the "every answer is equally valid" rule on [help/dont-ask]...