# Why was my question on what features in C# 10 are tied to the runtime closed?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, needs-more-focus

I asked this question, [Does C# 10 support the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76940005/does-c-sharp-10-support-the-net-framework), and it has been closed as “needs focus” (I am not sure how it was closed; I don’t see the close votes that normally appear, nor a moderator closing it).

How could it be made more clear?

Comment: You asked for list of things and it was closed as asking for list of things... Did you not ask for list of things? There is a good duplicate (which I can't currently find :( ) that discusses on how long/confirmed complete the list should be to be "focused"... While any list of language's features is by definition finite and countable (which was the main point of contention for "too broad") it is open to individual interpretation if the particular list is poorly defined.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov perhaps [Are questions asking for one exhaustive list on-topic?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/398264/208273) or one of the things linked from there?

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov:  am I to take "Needs focus" as "not a list"?  I don't see that elsewhere.   I'm not trying to argue that it shouldn't have been close or asking for it to be re-opened, I just want to understand the reason.  No comments by anyone saying "I'm voting to close this because X" (in fact doesn't seem to have any close votes), nor a mod or diamond saying the same thing.  Just closed.

Comment: @RyanM I had different one in mind (also indeed the one you found has similar vibe) - there was a question along the lines of "does list of features added in C++ specification version.X compared to version.X-1 narrow/focused enough or not and if self-answer would justify it"... with long arguing that longish list is still ok if anyone can verify that the resulting list is complete based on public facts (like language specification) and self-answering plays minor role by showing that indeed such list can be constructed.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/326951/are-questions-asking-for-feature-sets-of-specific-software-versions-on-topic is probably the question you were thinking of

Comment: Why the question post itself includes a list of things, which are just **repeated** in your answer? What is a value of the answer, if it just repeats the question post?

Comment: @jmoreno - yes.

Comment: @Tsyvarev list in the question presumably full list of C# 10 features, while answer is expecte to see which of those are usable in .Net Framework - basically "what C# 10 features do not require runtime support". (I have not checked the list myself)

Comment: @Tsyvarev: The question lists the changes, making it clear exactly what I was referring to, as well as giving a starting point for any answers or partial answers.  I repeated it in the answer so that it would be clear what requires a different platform and what just requires the compiler

Comment: @jmoreno: So, the question post is not a *request for the list*. The question post is actually **15 questions** of type "Whether a feature X requires a specific runtime or it is implemented by the compiler only". This is perfectly a reason of "too broad" closing.

Comment: @Tsyvarev:  It’s more like “If I upgrade to version 10, which features can I use”. Useful in making the decision as to whether one wants to use an “unsupported” configuration.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question Close Reasons - Definitions and Guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/417476/question-close-reasons-definitions-and-guidance)

Comment: "am I to take "Needs focus" as "not a list"?" Yes. Questions on Stack Overflow, like functions in one's code, are supposed to be about **one thing**. That's what "focus" entails. How *else* did you understand it? "The question lists the changes, making it clear exactly what I was referring to" **Clarity is not the problem. Focus is.** That's why the closure reason is "needs more focus", rather than "needs details or clarity".

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: it’s a potentially complex question, but it doesn’t take a book or website to answer, it doesn’t even take a particularly large paragraph.  Answer could be as simple “C#10 does not include any new features that will not run on the 4.8+ runtimes, although some would require a polyfill”.  That’s not the answer I gave, but if someone else did, I’d vote for it.

Answer (score 2):

Focus the question by **not** listing a bunch of C# 10 features in the question. If you want the question to be "is C# supported?", then there might be some room to argue over what "support" entails, but people answering the question would be perfectly free to mention which features do or don't work, or have caveats, or whatever.

But by putting the list of features up front, that makes it explicit that the question *expects* a significant treatment of *each* feature. Any of those is a coherent question by itself.

You claim that you were trying to emulate the existing question about C# 8, [Does C# 8 support the .NET Framework?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56651472) , which I note was very well received. I also note that this question **doesn't** mention any C# 8 features in the question; instead, it's motivated by a quirk of the IDE that makes it seem doubtful whether it's supported. I also note that the answers demonstrate that *the question can be answered without* reference to C# specific features.

Comment: It’s not a quirk in the IDE, it’s MS official stance: the language version targets a specific runtime.  Targeting other runtimes is undefined behavior.  The answer for C#8 **does** mention features.  IMO in an overly wordy manner, but it lists those features that work (compiler), can be made to work (compiler plus additional classes) and those that cannot work (runtime). Still, nice to see someone say something with words and not just a downvote.

Comment: "The answer for C#8 does mention features." - there are many answers, and some do not. More importantly, the *question does not*.